# Google App Engine maven spring project not able to deploy

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, maven

I am using eclipse. I have one Google App Engine project with spring is working locally and I am able to deploy it to google server.

Now I changed it with Maven integrity. It works locally fine. I am running it locally by maven build by setting appengine:devserver as goal.

But when try to deploy it to Google server, then it says error as follows.

Please help me.

Failed to initialize App Engine SDK at C:\Users\mviramga.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.8.6\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.6.jar
Unable to find C:\Users\mviramga.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.8.6\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.6.jar\lib\shared

```
pom.xml

<appengine.target.version>1.8.6</appengine.target.version>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>${appengine.target.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You're running java 7 isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I am using jdk7

Eclipse Project is taking appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.6.jar as SDK library and search for other subfolders so it gives error. If I select sdk installed external folder then it was not setting that folder.

So I did added that folder as library in project and gave highest priority and then it worked. Thanks for your all help.